# .NET Core "Files has invalid value" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hello I am developing an asp.net core mvc app when I build my solution I take this error;

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB3541 Files has invalid value "<<<<<<< HEAD". Illegal
> characters in path.   ToDo.Web    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4925

After that, when I click on the error description, the IDE redirects me to this section of the targets document.

```
<FindUnderPath Path="$(OutDir)" Files="@(_CleanOrphanFileWrites)">
  <Output TaskParameter="InPath" ItemName="_CleanOrphanFileWritesInOutput"/>
</FindUnderPath>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Files has invalid value "<<<<<<< HEAD". Illegal characters in path.

That value indicates that are part way through a git merge. Search in your repo for that string and resolve the git merge.

*Note I previously added this as a comment - but I suspect someone flagged it to be removed. I'd rather this be a comment, but adding it as an answer so that @mertagcakoyun can get up and running.*

Answer (score 0):

Just Delete **Obj** folder in your project and rebuild.

it will fix your error.